# append value of a javascript variable to a label without script

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to append the value of a javascript variable to a label without using jquery?

Eg:

```
Var global_message = "1234";

<label id="my-label">Test</label>
```

I want the value Test1234 to be displayed on the browser.

I dont want to write a jquery to say

```
$("#my-label").val() = $("#my-label").val()+global_message
```

Comment: The title says "_without script_"? You can't get a value of JS variable without a script. What is the real point here?

Comment: Are you asking for `document.getElementById('my-label').innerHTML += global_message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you want to access JavaScript variable directly in HTML and don't want to use any JavaScript/jQuery code.

But, You can not access JavaScript variable outside `<Script>` tag. 
HTML does not recognise any variable.

So you can use @WitVault answer if you want to use JavaScript and @Pranav C Balan using jQuery

Answer (score 2):

The [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is using to update the form elements value so it can't be used for updating text content of the label.

For updating `label` text use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method with a callback function, where the second argument in callback holds the old text.

```
$("#my-label").text(function(i, oldText){
  return oldText + global_message;
})
```

```js
var global_message = "1234";

$("#my-label").text(function(i, value) {
  return value + global_message;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label id="my-label">Test</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Pranav, But in my case, I have few html elements, whose content has to be modified, based on some dynamic value. These elements may or may not have something like a class/selector in common. This jquery can be done, but it needs a code change on my code base.. The label is rendered from the database, so i am lookiong for something that could be part of the Label's HTML definition so that i need not make a code change.

Comment: @jkr :  what you mean by this ___so i am lookiong for something that could be part of the Label's HTML definition so that i need not make a code change___ ???

Comment: Hi Pranav, I want to access a JavaScript variable directly in HTML

Answer (score 2):

```js
var global_message = "1234";

document.getElementById("my-label").innerText += global_message;
```

```html
<label id="my-label">Test</label>
```